# Configure org mode to use LuaLaTeX

Tags: unicode, emacs, latex, org-mode

I'm using emacs' `org-mode` to typeset notes and export them in pdf via LaTeX. Everything works fine, except when I use Unicode symbols, like in

```
\begin{equation}
  \left( \frac{P^2}{2m} + V(x,y,z) \right) Ψ = E Ψ
\end{equation}
```

where I use `Ψ`. Using `#+latex_compiler: lualatex` and

```
(setq org-latex-pdf-process
      '("lualatex -shell-escape -interaction nonstopmode %f"
        "lualatex -shell-escape -interaction nonstopmode %f"))
```

I have managed to export with more or less problems to PDF using LuaLaTeX, but the previews of the formulae (`C-c C-x C-l`) are completely broken for the ones with Unicode symbols.

What changes do I need to make in my emacs configuration to be able to use LuaLaTeX for *everything* related to LaTeX in `org-mode`?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Add the following code to your init file (N.B. it adds an element to the value of `org-preview-latex-process-alist`, so this code *must* be added after `org` is loaded - you may also need to `(require 'org)` or use `(eval-after-load 'org ...)` to avoid use-before-definition problems):

```
;; lualatex preview
(setq org-latex-pdf-process
  '("lualatex -shell-escape -interaction nonstopmode %f"
    "lualatex -shell-escape -interaction nonstopmode %f")) 

(setq luamagick '(luamagick :programs ("lualatex" "convert")
       :description "pdf > png"
       :message "you need to install lualatex and imagemagick."
       :use-xcolor t
       :image-input-type "pdf"
       :image-output-type "png"
       :image-size-adjust (1.0 . 1.0)
       :latex-compiler ("lualatex -interaction nonstopmode -output-directory %o %f")
       :image-converter ("convert -density %D -trim -antialias %f -quality 100 %O")))

(add-to-list 'org-preview-latex-process-alist luamagick)

(setq org-preview-latex-default-process 'luamagick)
```

I had to add a math-enabled font (XITS), so the org file itself looks like this now:

```
#+LATEX_HEADER: \usepackage{unicode-math}
#+LATEX_HEADER: \setmainfont{XITS}
#+LATEX_HEADER: \setmathfont{XITS Math}
#+LATEX_HEADER: \setmathfont[range={\mathcal,\mathbfcal},StylisticSet=1]{XITS Math}

* A formula for lua
\begin{equation}
  \left( \frac{P^2}{2m} + V(x,y,z) \right) Ψ = E Ψ
\end{equation}
```

Both export to PDF and preview seem to work.

Comment: BTW, this mechanism was added by Feng Shu in May 2016, so you need a fairly recent org in order to be able to use it. For earlier versions of org, you would need to modify the org code itself.

Comment: This somehow throws an error: `Error caused by user's config or system: /home/username/.doom.d/config.el, (void-variable org-preview-latex-process-alist)`

Comment: You are trying to modify the variable before it is defined. Find the place where it is modified in `config.el` and either `(require 'org)` before that or wrap the setting in `(eval-after-load 'org ...)`.

Comment: Thanks, that works! A note to future visitors using Doom Emacs, putting `(after! org (add-to-list 'org-preview-latex-process-alist luamagick) )` works too.

Answer (score 2):

I use windows 10 with Emacs 26.1 and the solution by @NickD worked for me with few minor changes

```
(setq org-latex-pdf-process
  '("lualatex -shell-escape -interaction nonstopmode %f"
    "lualatex -shell-escape -interaction nonstopmode %f"))

(setq luamagick '(luamagick :programs ("lualatex" "magick")
       :description "pdf > png"
       :message "you need to install lualatex and imagemagick."
       :use-xcolor t
       :image-input-type "pdf"
       :image-output-type "png"
       :image-size-adjust (1.0 . 1.0)
       :latex-compiler ("lualatex -interaction nonstopmode -output-directory %o %f")
       :image-converter ("magick convert -density %D -trim -antialias %f -quality 100 %O")))

(add-to-list 'org-preview-latex-process-alist luamagick)

(setq org-preview-latex-default-process 'luamagick)
```

Uses [magick](https://imagemagick.org) instead of `convert`. `convert` doesn't work as there is a default windows program called `convert.exe`

Answer (score 1):

And a `lualatex` entry to your org-preview-latex-process-alist, like this:

```lisp
(setq org-preview-latex-process-alist
  '((lualatex :programs ("lualatex" "dvisvgm")
                  :description "dvi > svg"
                  :message "you need to install the programs: lualatex and dvisvgm."
                  :image-input-type "dvi"
                  :image-output-type "svg"
                  :image-size-adjust (1.0 . 1.0)
                  :latex-compiler
                  ("lualatex --interaction=nonstopmode --shell-escape --output-format=dvi --output-directory=%o %f")
                  :image-converter
                  ("dvisvgm %f -n -b min -c %S -o %O"))))
(setq org-preview-latex-process 'lualatex)
```